# How to detect conversions in a configuration with a simple Paypal Buy button?

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, paypal, conversions, goal-tracking

I have a simple flow with a Paypal button:

[image]

```
   Website example.com        ===> Paypal interface ===>   Payment success page 
[simple Paypal BUY button]                                 example.com/success
[     without cart       ]
```

I would like to track **conversions** with Google Analytics and Facebook ads manager.

In order to do that, I have set a "Goal" in Google Analytics: `When example.com/success is visited, it is a purchase`. The same can be done with Facebook ads (see screenshot below).

### Problems:

- sometimes, after Paypal processes a payment, the customer doesn't go back to `example.com/success`. Then the conversion cannot be tracked.
- if someone visits the `success` page from multiple devices, it can be tracked as multiple conversions, which is a mistake!

### Question:

**How to detect conversions in a configuration with a simple Paypal Buy button?**

*Note: Here is how looks the conversion setup in Facebook:*

[image]

Comment: Have you specified a checkout redirect URL in Paypal for successful/cancelled purchases?

Comment: Yes @Yhorian I have set `example.com\success` as redirect URL after a successful purchase in Paypal's BUY button settings. But some users (<30%) don't necessarily wait for the redirection before closing the Paypal tab of browser. Then `example.com\success` is not shown. Then the FB pixel doesn't track this, then the conversion is not tracked. Do you have an idea?

Comment: It may not fit an answer as it's untested but have you considered a tracking event based on a javascript call-back? So Paypal opens in a new window and a websocket contacts the client in the original window to trigger the event when payment is confirmed with your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It works with Google Analytics, I haven't found for Facebook yet.

1. On your website, inside the Paypal button code `<form>...</form>`, add a field `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="(userid)">` where the userid is set with Javascript, taken from Google Analytics cookie, such as `document.cookie`'s `_ga`.
2. This [custom field will be passed to Paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384540/1422096) when the user clicks "BUY", and will be passed to IPN PHP code that runs after each successful payement. It can be retrieved in the IPN PHP code with `$_POST['custom']`.
3. In the Paypal IPN PHP code, you can [send a request to GoogleAnalytics to manually trigger a pageview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479516/1422096) of a virtual page named `example.com\thisisapurchase`. Something like this works:

   ```
   $data = array('v' => 1, 'tid' => 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'cid' => $_POST['custom'], 't' => 'pageview', 'dh' => 'www.example.com', 'dp' => 'thisisapurchase', 'dt' => 'thisisapurchase');
   $options = array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => http_build_query($data)));
   $context = stream_context_create($options);
   $result = file_get_contents('https://www.google-analytics.com/collect', false, $context);
   ```
4. In Google Analytics, create a "Goal" with destination = `example.com\thisisapurchase`

Then the visitor who visited the website, and who did a purchase (he visited a virtual page named `example.com\thisisapurchase`) will be seen as one unique visitor in Google Analytics.

Then you can reliably know from which source he comes from (referral, affiliate, etc.)